# Как сделать так, чтобы телеграм бот реагировал на слово фото?

Tags: python, парсер, telebot

код программы:

```
 from http import client
import telebot
import configg


client = telebot.TeleBot(configg.config['token']) 


#<------------------обработка полученных сообщений пользователя----------------->
@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def get_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет' :
        client.send_message(message.chat.id , 'Привет неизвестный пользователь')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'как дела?' :
        client.send_message(message.chat.id , 'пойдет, у тебя как?')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'какая погода?' :
        client.send_message(message.chat.id , 'ну вроде жить можно :)')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'как дома?' :
        client.send_message(message.chat.id , 'температура в доме +18 градусов \ кот спит')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'фото' :
        client.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo = 'https://clck.ru/bJ849', caption = 'foto') 
#<------------------обработка полученных сообщений пользователя----------------->


# -----------------------------------------------------------
client.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

При отправке слова 'привет' - бот реагирует , но не при слове 'фото'. Что следует сделать, чтобы он их отправлял.

Answer (score 1):

При отправке фотографий нужно быть уверенным, что вы отправляете именно фотографию или чистую ссылку на нее. Ваша ссылка ведет на страницу с фотографиями, а не на само фото. Можете проверить: выберите фотографию, скопируй URL этой фотографии и вставьте в
photo = "URL"

UPD:
Попробуйте так.

```
elif message.text.lower() == 'фото' :
    photo_source = requests.get("https://penzavzglyad.ru/images/uploads/2021/03/11/88db2b6320f164d39b27d80aac3b6551.jpg").content
    client.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo = photo_source, caption = 'foto')
```

Comment: Ссылку я изменил с "https://clck.ru/bJ849" на "https://penzavzglyad.ru/images/uploads/2021/03/11/88db2b6320f164d39b27d80aac3b6551.jpg", но это ничего не поменяло. Бот также не реагирует на слово "фото"

Comment: @CHeckPOint дополнил ответ